# Need help to simplify an equation

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I am computing an error estimate where  at the end I got the following term

$\|X_{k} - G\|\leq (q^{2^{k+2}} + q^{2^{k+3}}+ q^{2^{k+4}}....)q^{-3}\|Y_{0}\| + q^{2^{k+1}}.q^{-2}\|X_0\|$ ,

where $X_k$ is the sequence of approximations for $G$, $X_0$, and $Y_0$ are initial approximations. $0<q<1$.

I am stucked after this . I took  $q^{2^{k+1}}$ out side of the bracket but after that I am not able to simplify terms. Perhaps not able to sum the series. I want to know whether further simplifications is possible . I need help with this. I would be very much grateful for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the series in the parenthesis is
$$
q^{2^{k+2}}\cdot(1+q^{2^{k+2}}+q^{3\cdot2^{k+2}}+\cdots+q^{(2^n-1)\cdot2^{k+2}}+\cdots)\cdot q^{-3},
$$
which is less than
$$
q^{2^{k+2}}\cdot(1+q^{2^{k+2}}+q^{2\cdot2^{k+2}}+\cdots+q^{n\cdot2^{k+2}}+\cdots)\cdot q^{-3}=\frac{q^{2^{k+2}}}{1-q^{2^{k+2}}}\cdot q^{-3}.
$$
This upper bound is very easy to obtain and it may look crude but it has the correct order $q^{2^{k+2}-3}$ when $q\to0$ and it diverges just like the original sum when $q\to1$, hence, for all practical purposes it is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I almost got my answer. Only one thing is troubling me: As you said its order is $q^{2^{k+2}-3}$. Could I say that it is faster than the second order method but slower than the third order method. Because for the second order method it was coming out to be $q^{2^{k}}$.

Comment: The upper bound in the post is exactly of order $r^{2^k}$ for some $r$ in $(0,1)$ (apparently, $r=q^2$, because of the second term in the RHS).

Comment: Your answer helped me to go for further analysis. Thank you  again.